# How to write pyspark dataframe to HDFS and then how to read it back into dataframe?

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I have a very big pyspark dataframe. So I want to perform pre processing on subsets of it and then store them to hdfs. Later I want to read all of them and merge together. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- writing DataFrame to HDFS (Spark 1.6).

  ```
  df.write.save('/target/path/', format='parquet', mode='append') ## df is an existing DataFrame object.
  ```

some of the format options are `csv`, `parquet`, `json` etc.

- reading DataFrame from HDFS (Spark 1.6).

  ```
  from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
  sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
  sqlContext.read.format('parquet').load('/path/to/file')
  ```

the format method takes argument such as `parquet`, `csv`, `json` etc.

Comment: Hey I get attributError : DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'csv.
Also I need to read that dataframe later that is I think in new spark session.

Comment: what is the version of your spark installation?

Comment: spark version 1.6.1

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one doubt, while reading what if there are multiple files in that location. How to specify which file I want to read. Thanks

Comment: if you want to read only one file among many. you will have to just specify the full file path. if you want to read all the files you can use glob patterns like `*` in the path.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.

Comment: Sorry for one more question: Can you please tell how to delete those dataframes from HDFS afterwards.

Comment: to delete the data from hdfs you can use HDFS shell commands like `hdfs dfs -rm -rf <path>`. you can execute this using python subprocess like `subprocess.call(["hdfs", "dfs", "-rm", "-rf", `path`])`

Comment: what is target path? where does hdfs actually live on my pc?