# Python write to hdfs file

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, file-handling

What is the best way to create/write/update a file in **remote** HDFS from local python script?

I am able to list files and directories but writing seems to be a problem.

I have searched [hdfs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs) and [snakebite](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite) but none of them give a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

try HDFS liberary.. its really good
You can use write().
https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdfs.client.Client.write

Example:

to create connection:

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
client = InsecureClient('http://host:port', user='ann')

from json import dump, dumps
records = [
  {'name': 'foo', 'weight': 1},
  {'name': 'bar', 'weight': 2},
]

# As a context manager:
with client.write('data/records.jsonl', encoding='utf-8') as writer:
  dump(records, writer)

# Or, passing in a generator directly:
client.write('data/records.jsonl', data=dumps(records), encoding='utf-8')
```

For CSV you can do

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read.csv("file.csv")
with client.write('path/output.csv', encoding = 'utf-8') as writer:
  df.to_csv(writer)
```

Comment: Why do you use json library ? What is the reason ? How do I do if I do not have json but CSV ?

Comment: i have added that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

#### What's wrong with other answers

They use **WebHDFS**, which is **not enabled by default**, and **insecure** without Kerberos or Apache Knox.

This is what the [`upload` function](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdfs.client.Client.upload) of that `hdfs` library you linked to uses.

#### Native (more secure) ways to write to HDFS using Python

You can use `pyspark`.

Example - [How to write pyspark dataframe to HDFS and then how to read it back into dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290548/how-to-write-pyspark-dataframe-to-hdfs-and-then-how-to-read-it-back-into-datafra)

---

`snakebite` has been mentioned, but [it doesn't write files](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite/issues/37)

---

[`pyarrow` has a FileSystem.open() function](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.HadoopFileSystem.open.html#pyarrow.HadoopFileSystem.open) that should be able to write to HDFS as well, though I've not tried.

Comment: that is true..but  if they are writing to hdfs without spark their is no other very good option.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a complicated library built for HDFS, you can also simply use the requests package in python for HDFS as:

```
import requests
from json import dumps
params = (
('op', 'CREATE')
)
data = dumps(file)  # some file or object - also tested for pickle library
response = requests.put('http://host:port/path', params=params, data=data)
```

If response is 200, then your connection is working! This technique lets you use all the utitities given by Hadoop's RESTful API: ls, md, get, post, etc.

You can also convert CURL commands to python through this:

1. Get Command for HDFS: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html
2. Convert to python: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Might want to update Hadoop link with latest version