# input data from multiple source into hadoop(HDFS)

Tags: python, hadoop

how i can put different data from multiple sources into HDFS using python

i already tried SQL file using pyspark(in Pycharm IDEA) and it worked.

Now i need more functions that allowed me to ingest diffrent others data into HDFS

Answer (score 0):

PySpark is very versatile - it can read multiple inputs via Streaming/SQL. You'll need to be more specific about what sources you are trying to load from.

However, if you want a more accessible way to ingest lots of data, that is what [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) was explicitly built for. If you prefer not having to write lots of code, then you may also look at [apache-nifi](/questions/tagged/apache-nifi), which integrates nicely within the Hadoop ecosystem.

Comment: No matter the source, just i have to put different type of data into hdfs.The tools that I am going to use must have python code

Comment: Such as...? And what errors are you running into when you _try_ to load into HDFS?

Comment: (.csv .json .txt ) fiels. Also i  collected tweets from twitter using tweepy but i can't find the function that allow me to send them to hdfs

Comment: Spark can read all those and write to hdfs. There isn't one in tweepy. That's only a Twitter client, and has no relation to Hadoop... You'd need to parallelize that to a Spark dataframe, at the very least. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926758/python-write-to-hdfs-file

Comment: please sir i tried for csv file then i get this error : <AttributeError: module 'spark' has no attribute 'read'>

Comment: Sounds like you're using a module, for example you have `import pyspark as spark`, and not a SparkSession object. I suggest you create a new post for new errors, though

Comment: OneCricketeer Hi sir, for the files(CSV,JSON,TXT,SQL) i have ingested all of them  successfully thank u for your answered. But now I have to do it with GUI (i'll develop interface which does the ingestion) can i do the ingestion of those files at the same time in parallel.

Comment: Hi sir Please how i can read the files saved in haddop as parquet from hadoop  directly

Comment: I already told you Spark is capable of this. Python has no native Parquet support, as far as I know